# Jenkins- build fail with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/mvn/GlobalMavenConfig

Tags: jenkins

Did any one experience a similar problem like below or may share some thought on what possibly went wrong here:

```
Parsing POMs
FATAL: jenkins/mvn/GlobalMavenConfig
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/mvn/GlobalMavenConfig
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.getSettings(MavenModuleSet.java:663)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.<init>(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1090)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:882)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:636)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:580)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:491)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
```

Comment: Well, `jenkins/mvn/GlobalMavenConfig` is not found in Classpath. That's pretty strange since `GlobalMavenConfig` is in *jenkins-core-<your version>.jar* . Make sure that *<Path to jenkins.war>/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-<version>.jar/jenkins/mvn/GlobalMavenConfig.class* actually exists. If there is no such class then download correct version of `jenkins-core-<your version>.jar` or newer version of jenkins.(Path to jenkins.war is usually /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war at least on debian-based Linux)

Answer (score 4):

> > In general, `NoClassDefFoundError`in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

You may take a look at [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) and [great blog post](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html).

It seems that version of maven-plugin in  in `<Full path to jenkins.war>/WEB-INF/plugins` is newer than version of jenkins-core in `<Full path to jenkins.war>/WEB-INF/lib` and *jenkins/mvn/GlobalMavenConfig* [was added](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/b8adcb43dd73f8bcc3ff00558e0f7e587929cec6) in [1.515](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/changelog.html#L281), so your maven-plugin version may be >= 1.515 and jenkins-core version may be < 1.515. Perhaps, you either followed [steps that are mentioned here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-UsingcustombuildsofpluginsincludedintheJenkinsWAR) or there is something wrong with your *jenkins.war*.

How to verify it:

Check jenkins version and also `jenkins-core-<your version>.jar`. You may found `jenkins-core-<your version>.jar` in `<Path to jenkins.war>/WEB-INF/lib/` folder. Classes for maven-plugin are in `<Path to jenkins.war>/WEB-INF/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar`. Maven-plugin version mentioned in `<Path to jenkins.war>/WEB-INF/plugins/maven-plugin/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

How to fix it:

You may install latest version of jenkins or at least [install correct](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-UsingcustombuildsofpluginsincludedintheJenkinsWAR) [maven-plugin](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin requires a newer version of a jar that is already installed with Jenkins, most of the time you will run into conflict since Jenkins loads first by default. Per the [Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+Structure#PluginStructure-Classloader), if you simply add the following Maven plugin and configuration to the build in the pom.xml of your Jenkins plugin, it will override the default behavior so the classes in your plugin jars are loaded first:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <pluginFirstClassLoader>true</pluginFirstClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```